# Solr says it's running on port 8983 but can't access admin panel, also lsof missing

Tags: solr, lsof

My Solr version is 7.2.0 and Java version: openjdk version "9-internal"

After I run `bin/solr start`, it says this:

> NOTE: Please install lsof as this script needs it to determine if Solr is listening on port 8983

But I can't install lsof, because I don't have permission from my hosting provider.

However this message is shown:

> Started Solr server on port 8983 (pid=1207). Happy searching!

When I try to access admin panel by mydomain.com:8983/solr/, browser cannot connect to the server.

So I suppose that Solr server isn't running even it writes "Happy searching" message, as it can't determine if Solr is listening on port 8983.

Is there any way how to solve lsof problem? But the second question is, why Solr server isn't running?

Comment: `lsof` must be installed on Red Hat distribs so that solr scripts can work correctly, that's it. If you don't have the permission, wouldn't it be simpler to ask your hosting provider to handle it directly ?

Comment: Note also that you have to be root to properly install the installation script.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check solr server status?

```
/bin/solr status
```

I'm not sure but java 9 might cause to this problem.

Comment: I came across something about your problem in 'solr ref guide'. Check this [link] (http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/ref-guide/apache-solr-ref-guide-5.2.pdf) (Run the Solr Installation Script)

Comment: `bin/solr status` found Solr process 289 running on port 8983 with some informations about version and memory etc...Solr installation script must be run as root as @EricLavault wrote. So probably I will ask my hosting provider to install lsof, but the problem can be still caused by java version as well.

Comment: In this guide it says: "The previous command extracts the install_solr_service.sh script from the archive into the current
directory. If installing on Red Hat, please make sure lsof is installed before running the Solr installation script (su
do yum install lsof). The installation script must be run as root:                $ sudo bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-5.0.0.tgz (here u can write ur own solr version)